# Selecting random background colour from array. Javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I am new to coding and have an assignment where i need to include random colour picker for the background. The colours are red, green, yellow and blue. I have been researching and playing around with it but I have come to a stand still. Any help telling me how to do it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting random value from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to target the css properties.

```
color = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"];

        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
        console.log(randomNum);
        var randomColor = color[randomNum];
        $("body").css("background-color", randomColor);
```

This might help you.

Comment: OP asked for javascript not JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript part

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"]; //Array of colors
var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; //Pick one randomly
document.body.style.background = randomColor; //Apply the color on the body background
```